# document.referrer is providing accented letters

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using document.referrer for grabbing previous URL of current page and sending it to a curl file,that curl file again send this variable to a PHP file for saving it into data base. The problem is that on saving into database I'm getting URL value as accented letters like

```
†Ûiÿû®û(~×(›û®û(~×â•ïðŠwhÂÏÚžØ¦j­î
```

I've used `base64` coding scheme in my php file.The collation of MySQL column is `latin1_swedish_ci`.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like character encoding mismatch to me.  For starters, I would avoid using `latin1` and change the database to use utf-8.

Answer (score 3):

As the commenter suggests, I think this is simply a problem where the encoding of the URL isn't the same as the encoding of your database. Using `utf-8` on your database tables would solve most (if not all) of your problems. Here is a two part article ([part 1](http://www.borngeek.com/2008/07/25/unicode-and-the-web-part-1/) and [part 2](http://www.borngeek.com/2008/08/18/unicode-and-the-web-part-2/)) that discusses how to use `utf-8` in PHP and MySQL.